# Django - Saving data without using input fields/forms

Tags: django

I am a novice, apologies if this question seems silly. I need to save some data into MySQL database. There are no input fields. The user should click a button, and a table is updated. The data to be saved is two foreign keys and a PK.

Here is my model

```
class Bids(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    userid = models.ForeignKey(Writer, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='userid ')
    orderid = models.ForeignKey(Orders, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='orderids')
    biddatetime=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I have tried writing several functions to save these fields into table bids but no joy so far. Hers's a sample.

```
def saveBid(request):
    if request.method!= "POST":
        return HttpResponse("Action Not Allowed")
    else:
        biddatetime=request.POST.get('biddatetime')

        bids= Bids(biddatetime=biddatetime)
        order=Orders(id=id)

        user= CustomUser()
        user.save()
  

        bids.save()
```

Pls assist

Comment: Are you using a form with the two foreign key values already populated? or is "userid" being used after you call user.save() providing more code would help..

Comment: userid and orderid are already populated.I am just getting these from a table that is already there. I need to update table bid based on orderid, userid and now bidid.

Comment: Sorry, this does not help much, please add more information in the question about the id's and clearly state the values that are sent in the POST request.

Answer (score 0):

I would try sending a POST request to `saveBid` using [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) and what error you're getting. Post the response from postman here for more help.

It could be that

1. `biddatetime` is a string and not a datetime.
2. On row `order=Orders(id=id)` you have no variable named id in your code, this will raise error.
3. In your model Bids the fields `userid` and `orderid` do not allow null and blank.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**strptime()**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) to convert `biddatetime` to `datetime object`.

Try something like that:

```
from datetime import datetime

def saveBid(request):
    if request.method != "POST":
        return HttpResponse("Action Not Allowed")
    else:
        query = request.POST
        # See Format Codes - link below
        biddatetime = datetime.strptime(query.get('biddatetime'), "%Y-%m-%d")
        # get Order
        order = Orders.objects.get(id=query.get("order_id")
        # create CustomUser
        user = CustomUser.objects.create(username="username")
        # create Bids
        bids = Bids.objects.create(biddatetime=biddatetime, userid=user, orderid=order)
```

[**create()**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#create) method:

> create(**kwargs)
>
> A convenience method for creating an object and saving it all in one
> step. Thus:
>
> ```
> p = Person.objects.create(first_name="Bruce", last_name="Springsteen")
> ```

Linkt to [Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

See also [**Creating objects**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects).

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you are not using django Form or ModelForm?

```
class BidForm(forms.Form):
    biddatetime = forms.DateTimeField()
    .... // other fields

@require_POST
def saveBid(request):
    form = BidForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        biddatetime = form.cleaned_data.get('biddatetime')
        ... // do same for similar fields.
        
        
        ...// after user save
        user.refresh_from_db()  // post insert you will get the id value for the row
        bids = Bids(
            biddatetime=biddatetime,
            userid=user.userid,
            orderid=order.orderids)
        bids.save()
```

I am assuming you are using the id value for user after save if thats not the case you can  ignore it.